# No sound in output clips. RTSP to mp4 ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I was using the following command for recording input streams to mp4 into 10 seconds clip. But since few days there is no voice in the output mp4 clips.
Command is

```
 ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -c copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 output%d.mp4
```

[ffmpeg output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAAAq.png)

I think its because of the format of input stream but i don't know for sure and also, i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: The complete console output from your command is required.

Comment: Output screenshot attached.

Comment: Please don't make images of text. Just copy and paste it here or re-direct the output to a text file: `ffmpeg -i input output 2> log.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the following command.

```
      ffmpeg -i rtsp://localhost:8554/mystream -c:a aac -c:v copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 output%d.mp4
```

changing `-c` to `-c:a aac -c:v`